# How to set xampp open localhost:8080 instead of just localhost

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, port

I use XAMPP 1.7.3. Apache and MySQL installed. Nothing else.

Apache installed on default port 80. Clicking on Admin next to Apache opens `http://localhost/xampp/`. Which works as expected.

I navigated to `xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf` and edited it. Set `Listen 8080`. Now `http://localhost:8080/xampp/` works as expected but the Admin button still opens `http://localhost/xampp/` which does not open anything. I have restarted the computer after doing so with no results.

How to make XAMPP apache admin open `localhost:8080/xampp` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the admin button will open the default configuration always. It simply contains a link to `localhost/xampp` and it doesn't read the server configuration.

If you change the default settings, you know what you changed and you can enter the URL directly in the browser.

Comment: In Version 3.2.4, you can set the port @ Control panel > config > services and port settings > Apache > Main Port

Answer (score 28):

The port that the Admin button references is configurable.  In the XAMPP install folder there is a `xampp-control.ini` file.  Changing the Apache entry under `[ServicePorts]` will affect the url the Admin button opens.

```
[ServicePorts]
Apache=8080
```

Comment: Or in GUI: Control Panel - Config - Service and Port Settings and set the port - that way XAMPP will overwrite this itself.

Comment: Hi @john: If i follow your answer, still i just confused.. because .. in my Xampp folder, there is no file called xampp-control.ini .. so can you help me?.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Steps using XAMPP GUI:

Step-1: Click on **Config** button

[image]

Step-2: Click on **Service and Port Settings** button

[image]

Final step: Change your **port and Save**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can get loccalhost page by writing `localhost/xampp` or by writing `http://127.0.0.1` you will get the local host page. After starting the apache serve that can be from wamp, xamp or lamp.

Answer (score 0):

I agree and found this file under xammp-control the type of file is configuration.
When I changed it to 8080 it worked automagically!

Answer (score 0):

Open XAMPP look below the X to close the program there is a Config option click it then click service and port settings then under Apache change your main port to whatever you changed it to in the config file then click save and your good to go.