# How to call my API in XAMPP when this server has an IP different than localhost?

Tags: angularjs, rest, xampp

I installed the new XAMPP 7.4 in macOS Catalina and the window is very different than before. I press Mount and it runs. But I have Angularjs projects that calls API Rest Laravel projects in htdocs, but doesn't work because it calls to localhost or to the local IP of the computer, but I don't know how XAMPP works now.

XAMPP creates a new ip where is htdocs and I access to the folder throw the IP but my Angularjs projects can't access because they don't know the IP, only call to 127.0.0.1.

How can I configure XAMPP to work with localhost or how can I configure Angularjs to call to that IP without affect my production server?

Thank you!

Comment: Anybody please. Will I have to install an alternative to XAMPP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a Status IP like localhost:8080, you have to go to the Network tab in XAMPP and press Enable on the localhost:8080 option. I feel ashamed for taking too long to find this. Thank you.

Comment: I am glad to hear you could resolve it! Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have not done this before, my answer is based on my angularjs experience and a brief search.

#### Trying a brand new project

In this article (which you have probably already seen and tried): https://kode-blog.io/angularjs-install-and-configure there is a very relevant segment, namely Step 1: "You can directly create the folder angular-js in drive C:\xampp\htdocs". I understand your issues is just vaguely related, though you could try following this article step-by-step with a brand new project

#### XAMPP to local/virtual host

If I understood correctly you are looking for a way to modify the XAMPP/AngularJS serving to the same IP. Let's try setting XAMPP to localhost first:
[Setting up a virtual host on XAMPP on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206597/setting-up-a-virtual-host-on-xampp-on-mac) or [How to set xampp open localhost:8080 instead of just localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152231/how-to-set-xampp-open-localhost8080-instead-of-just-localhost) and also more detailed, step-by-step ones: https://jonathannicol.com/blog/2012/03/11/configuring-virtualhosts-in-xampp-on-mac/

#### Serving AngularJS to a specific host

AngularJS is a lot less flexible than Angular 2+ ([Set default host and port for ng serve in config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762125/set-default-host-and-port-for-ng-serve-in-config-file)) when it comes to serving a host. You could try using http-server and node.js (first answer here: [How to create a localhost server to run an AngularJS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528922/how-to-create-a-localhost-server-to-run-an-angularjs-project) but also check out other answers, there is some extra useful info there)

#### Extra bits

What you are trying seems to be absolutely feasible and done by others ([Setup AngularJS and NodeJS on Xampp Web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596297/setup-angularjs-and-nodejs-on-xampp-web-server) or https://www.quora.com/Can-we-use-AngularJS-in-XAMPP) but it's not the most common thing.

I know that this answer does not directly give you an easy-to-implement-one-single-line-of-wondercode, but I hope it will start discussion at least and result in something more useful.